# Python Flask on IIS: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, iis

We followed this guide on setting up Flask on IIS https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3 and it works well but when we do `flask run` from VS code we get the following

```
PS J:\Apps\prod> flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'wsgi.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

About the development server line and the production WSGI server line - is this purely because we set it up in IIS? Should we have followed a different route than what was in that guide we followed?

Everything else I'm seeing seems to be only relevant to *nix based systems i.e using Gunicorn

Thanks

Comment: try this `export FLASK_ENV=production` to set environment variable to production mode and `flask run`

Comment: You have to follow official materials like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022#configure-the-httpplatform-handler, not any other post from the internet, and note that "We recommend using HttpPlatform to configure your apps, as the WFastCGI project is no longer maintained."

Comment: Thank you but the thing is, that doesn't work - https://serverfault.com/questions/1104949/python-flask-on-iis-httpplatform-doesnt-load-when-visiting-hostname

Answer (score 3):

The guide you followed, though captured quite a few screen shots and contained a lot of information, does not describe the recommended approach from Microsoft, because Python via FastCGI on IIS is no longer supported as quoted from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022#configure-the-httpplatform-handler),

> We recommend using HttpPlatform to configure your apps, as the WFastCGI project is no longer maintained.

To get up-to-date information on this setup, you can refer to [my blog post](https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/). I list the key points below to make a standalone answer.

### Preparation

Prepare a folder such as `C:\flask-test`, and create `app.py` as

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():
        return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

    return app
```

and `wsgi.py`

```
from app import create_app

application = create_app()
```

Then install both `flask` and `waitress`,

```
pip install flask waitress
```

And test that both `flask run` and `waitress-serve` work,

```
PS C:\flask-test> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

PS C:\flask-test> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m waitress --port 9000 wsgi:application
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:9000
```

### IIS Integration

Add a `web.config` file in this folder to enable HttpPlatformHandler,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\python.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\lextudio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" arguments="-m waitress --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% wsgi:application">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then on IIS you can create a new site to point to `C:\flask-test`.

> More details can be found in my blog post, especially on troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a folder such as C:\flask-test, and create app.py as

```
from flask import Flask
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Debug/Development
    # app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
    # Production
    http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Note: Install gevent using pip install gevent

Answer (score 0):

You can use [waitress](https://pypi.org/project/waitress/). It's a production WSGI server.

```
from waitress import serve
serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

It's a drop-in replacement to your classic app.run().